# Testing Database using laravel dusk

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-dusk

I am testing my laravel application using laravel dusk but the problem is that I am unable to use `assertDatabaseHas`function. When I run `php artisan dusk` command I got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint' not found in 
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Constraints\HasIn
Database.php on line 8
```

[image]

Here is my code:

```
$this->assertDatabaseHas('teams', [
    'name' => $data['team_name'],
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your version of phpunit:

```
phpunit --version
```

If you are are running v6 you might have trouble because it expects a namespaced class. In that case you either have to switch to an older version of phpunit, e.g. locally installed for your project and then run like this:

```
php vendor/bin/phpunit --version
```

or you might have to update your Laravel-project, which is probably more work as you might have to change parts of your code.

Comment: Thanks, Problem solved after switching to PHPUnit 5.7 version. :)

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed you should stay on 6.1 and `use PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint` instead. Then just extend `Constraint`

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu well it's a class from Laravel framework. Changing code there is not a good idea, as you usually don't want to maintain your own fork. The better option would be an upgrade as I mentioned above, but unfortunately Laravel has breaking changes in minor versions, making it non-trivial for some existing projects to switch to a newer version.